# how to translating characters to Unicode alphabet

Tags: haskell

1. Unicode alphabet

a. getChar n which gives the character of a given Unicode n.

- need to convert a Char to an Int representing its codepoint.

b. getCode c which gives the Unicode of a given character c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fromEnum` to convert a `Char` to an `Int` representing its codepoint. The opposite conversion is done by `toEnum` (e.g. `toEnum 65 :: Char` gives `'A'`).

Alternatively, use `ord` and `chr` from module `Data.Char`.